# Spring boot jUnit test fails because of "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException"

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing an end-to-end test for the following class in my Spring boot project, but I receive `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` error because `No qualifying bean of type 'com.boot.cut_costs.service.CustomUserDetailsService' available`.

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsServices;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsDtoValidator createUserDetailsDtoValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestBody UserDetailsDto userDetailsDTO, HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result) {
        // ...
        userDetailsServices.saveIfNotExists(username, password, name);
        // ...
        if (authenticatedUser != null) {
            AuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, authenticatedUser.getName());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials provided");
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AuthenticationController.class)
public class AuthenticationControllerFTest {

    @Autowired 
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
        Mockito.when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("DUMMY_USERNAME");
        Mockito.when(
                authenticationManager.authenticate(Mockito
                    .any(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)))
                .thenReturn(authentication);

        //....
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/signup")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(exampleUserInfo)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
    }
}
```

I think this error happens because it in the test environment the spring context isn't loaded the same way as in dev/production environment. How should I fix this issue ?

**Edit 1**

My Spring boot application entry point is `App.java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the cause is context, too. Try this:

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"location/to/test-config.xml"})

Comment: What is "locations" ? what does it point to ?

Comment: Please refer to: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx

Comment: You may be interested by this article (point 3) : https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/ and the annotations `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})`

Comment: This is a spring boot application, therefore there's no xml configuration file to pull in.

Comment: Spring Boot will automatically do the job with `@SpringBootTest`. See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config).

Comment: @Thoomas I added `@SpringBootTest` and removed `@WebMvcTest(...)` and it fails: `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc'`

Comment: Try to use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` with `@SpringBootTest`. 
Apparently, `@WebMvcTest` only loads the controller configuration. That's why you had this DI error (with it, you have to provide mocks for your services).

Comment: @Thoomas it worked, you can post it so I accept it as the answer. 
Right now, the issue is that it hits attemptAuthentication method in `JWTAuthenticationFilter` class (which extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`). While n non-test environment, it doesn't hit that method as the requests to the `/signup` endpoint is excepted from being authorized by `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login/**", "/signup/**");` in `WebSecurityConfig` (which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`)
Do you know what could be the reason ?

Comment: Answer added. I'm afraid I can't help you on the security problem. Maybe these [answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JWTAuthenticationFilter+isaccepted%3Ayes) might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@WebMvcTest` only loads the controller configuration. That's why you had this DI error (with it, you have to provide mocks for your services). So, if you need  to inject your services, you can use `@SpringBootTest`.

If you use `@SpringBootTest`, you also have to use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`to configure `MockMvc`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull in the configuration which does the component scanning for your beans using @ContextConfiguration annotation on your test class.

This could potentially load configuration that is not needed or may even cause the tests to fail so a safer way to do it would be to write a configuration class yourself with only what you need to get the test to run (potentially just the relevant component scan for your beans). If you write this config class as a static inner class of your test class then you can pull this config in by just using the @ContextConfiguration annotation with no parameters.

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTestClass {

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
     ...
   }

   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan("my.package")
   public static class MyTestConfig {
   }
```

Comment: This is a spring boot application, therefore ther is no config file to pull in.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh ah, well I've updated my answer. You still should be able to do this to manually force the spring boot application to component scan in your test context like this.

Comment: I added @ContextConfiguration(classes = {App.class}) to the test class, and it didn't resolve the issue. I edited my question and exaplined about `App.java`

Comment: a nice workaround